# Label text not changing after view controller is pushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I have a tab bar application. My main view controller which is pushed when the app is run has a label with text depicting a time. When a button in my main view controller is pressed, another tab bar view controller is pushed, with a tab bar at the bottom. When another button is pressed in my tab bar view controller, I want the label in my main view controller to change text, in addition to repushing the main view controller so I can see the label with the changed text. However, after pressing the button in the tab bar controller and pushing the main view controller, the label's text just doesn't change. Before the tab bar view controller is pushed, I can change the label's text in the main view controller. However, after the tab bar controller is pushed and then the main view controller is repushed, I can't change anything in my main view controller label. It's almost as if my code freezes when the main view controller is repushed.

Comment: it's not possible to push a view controller that is already present in navigation stack. You should pop your tabbar view to main view. and set ur label text in viewwillappear

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Salman is right. You have to put code in viewWillAppear to change text in label.

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this 
1)you make a object of main class in first tabbar view and assign property, when you pushed first tabbar view (on button pressed) you write like this

```
firsttabbarObj.mainViewController=self;
```

in main view controller you make a method that take a string and assign to label then in first tabbar when you pop you view you write this code

```
[self.mainViewController setText:string];
[appDelegate.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

then label value is changed and you see the result what you want :-)